# Downgrade a SWF file

Tags: flash, 3d, actionscript-2

So I've made a 3D animation in flash cs5.5 using ( AS3 and flashPlayer 10+ ), but I need it to be in flash player 9 or smaller. Any ideas how to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you've got two approaches to this:

1. The timeline one: Right click tween > **Convert to Frame by Frame Animation**. This will add to your filesize and also, if you have named symbols, you need to make sure the symbol has an instance name on **all** frames. Also, making changes to the tweens means going back and forth between documents and converting all the time
2. Using a Flash Player 9 compatible 3D library. If it's simple/lightweight stuff, [FIVe3D](http://five3d.mathieu-badimon.com/) is pretty awesome (small/easy to use (mimics the Flash drawing API)). You can also try older versions of [Away3D](http://away3d.com) or [Papervision3D](http://blog.papervision3d.org/), although I'm not sure if you get vector support with the actionscript 2 versions. I recommend trying FIVe3D first. The main advantage for this approach is that once you've redone your tweens with code, it's much easier to change/adjust. If you're comfortable with a bit of Flash IDE scripting, you can whip out script to [export the tween](http://flashthusiast.com/2008/11/04/understanding-flash-cs4-motion-xml/).